# Subject that just sends an event like a notification and not necessarily an object [RxJava]

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, publishsubject

I have a use case where I have to pull requests from a queue. I have to pull a new request one when I am done processing the last one. It looks like I would have to use a `Subject` that could help me to trigger an event on it after I am done with the last pulled request. I came across an API `PublishSubject` where I can keep on posting events whenever I like but what I need to send a new object to the subject. But I need to define it with an object type and then call it with `onNext(<Object>)` for the next event. What I want is a subject that does not need to send any specific object and just gets triggered like a notification (Something like onComplete()). How can I achieve this?

Comment: You still need to send an object of some kind. If you're using Kotlin you can use `Unit` otherwise, you can use a static plain `Object`

Comment: Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#nulls